# created tf listener, how to rosbag?

Tags: rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run `tf tf_echo /Pioneer3AT/map /Pioneer3AT/base_link` and compute exact data needed (so far so good):

```
...
At time 1407419581.729
- Translation: [-8.999, -22.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.000, 0.850. 0.526]
         in RPY [0.000. -0.000, 2.034]
...
```

I set up the following listener:

```
import roslib
import rospy
import tf
import sys, traceback
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_P3AT')
    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            now = rospy.Time(0)
            (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", now)
    except: (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException):
        continue

    print 'translation: ',trans
    print 'rotation: ', rot

    rate.sleep()
```

Prints out the correct data as above.
Next step: I would like to record this transform with rosbag.

Is this just a matter of publishing this data within my listener file, then running `rostopic echo`, then running `rosbag record`? Thanks for reading this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189776/created-tf-listener,-how-to-rosbag?/) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rosbag record` to directly record `/tf`. As you mentioned, you have confirmed this using `tf_echo` and should work fine. You can later `rosbag play` that info.

Your tf_listener on the other hand is just to lookup transforms from `/tf` and then perform some math or logic on that. You do not need to publish the specific transform from your tf_listener nor do you need to keep `rostopic echo` running.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thanks for your answer. And, I have seen this answer, applied it before, but I did not get the desired data format, which is my reason for producing the listener. Do you have a recommendation to record the tf listener that I have produced above?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-13**:
I don't see why that doesn't work for you. Another option I can think of is to use `rosbag filter`. You will need to specify a python expression for your case. This is the syntax;
`rosbag filter <in-bag> <out-bag> <expression>` so you are basically filtering the original bag that has all the tf.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-13**:
This doesn't work for me because I need to perform some math on some of the other transforms. I am wanting to record the exact data provided by the tf listener from above. Is this not straight forward to broadcast and record?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-13**:
Yes, you can "broadcast" it on another topic after you perform the math. You can then record just that topic (you don't need to `echo` it).
Alternatively, if you are going to use a tf broadcaster then you are back to square one because that will again be part of `/tf`.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-13**:
What do I do if I just want to record the data from the listener file above? Is this a matter of publishing the listener data?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-13**:
Yes. Publish the data on a topic in whatever msg format you want. And then bag it.